Azure OpenTelemetry Exporter duplicates logs
I have a simple python script to export logs into an app insights trace table by following this example, however, the log entries get duplicated. What could be the reason?

# example.py

import logging
if os.getenv("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"):

    from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor

    configure_azure_monitor(logger_name=__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info(f"Logging configured.")


I also already tried to disable propagation on the Azure/Otel libs, but nothing worked
_azure_logger = logging.getLogger("azure")
_azure_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
_azure_logger.propagate = False

_otel_logger = logging.getLogger("opentelemetry")
_otel_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
_otel_logger.propagate = False




Have you checked this MSDoc. @Bennimi

According to the MSDoc, it is mentioned that:

Duplicate telemetry is often caused if you create multiple instances of processors or exporters. Make sure that you run only one exporter and processor at a time for each telemetry pillar (logs, metrics, and distributed tracing).

You can resolve this by setting OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER to None when enabling logs in the console.
Environment: export OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER="None"
Also, verify the other root causes for the duplicate entries conflict when retrieving the traces in application insights monitoring to avoid the issue.
By referring to this MS Doc for configuring telemetry, I have executed below python code with few modifications (environment variable) and worked as expected without any duplicate entries as shown.
Note: Check if the logger does not have any other handlers like (Azure, Telemetry) existed before adding a new handler to avoid duplicate metrics.
Firstly, I have executed below code to get the traces in azure application insights with the get_tracer method. I have received the unique entries, but the message item is displaying in dependencies rather than traces.
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace
import logging
configure_azure_monitor(
    connection_string="InstrumentationKey=1ee3529f-aa9e-43d8-ae14-bbdbfc998060;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=e75c111f-2bxxxx6a04ed"
)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

with tracer.start_as_current_span("hello") as span:
    logger.info("Hi Jahnavi") 

_otel_logger = logging.getLogger("opentelemetry")
_otel_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)



Then I have modified code according to your requirement to display the trace item messages with unique telemetry logs as shown below and worked as expected.
import logging
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs.export import BatchLogRecordProcessor as tel
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorLogExporter as mon

from opentelemetry._logs import (get_logger_provider,
    set_logger_provider)
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs import (
    LoggerProvider,LoggingHandler)
set_logger_provider(LoggerProvider())
azure_exptr = mon(
    connection_string="InstrumentationKey=1ee3529f-aa9e-43d8-ae14-bbdbfc998060;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=e75c1"xxxx
)
get_logger_provider().add_log_record_processor(tel(azure_exptr))

azure_handler = LoggingHandler()
azure_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
azure_logger.addHandler(azure_handler)
azure_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
azure_logger.info("Hishd")



Reference SO by @Sampath for different levels of logs tracing in app insights.

thanks for your thread, while it didn´t solve my issue (it was some misconfig of the AppInsights), this is probably helpful for others.

What is the misconfiguration u had. @Bennimi

i am not sure, I tested with a new AppInsights and didn´t see the duplicates. I now use this one and deleted the old. Do you have an idea why this could have happend?

If the specific application insight is also receiving logs from any other Azure resource or the diagnostic settings enabled to get the logs from any other resource, it may receive duplicates. @Bennimi

Have you checked the MS Doc given above. @Bennimi

Checked the doc? @Bennimi

yeap, and again, it was NOT the python code but the AppInsights

@Bennimi: Good to accept the solution if it has helped. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO link
